# detect deleted image from photo gallery in swift

Tags: ios, swift, photo, phimagemanager

I am saving local identifiers of PHAssets of photo gallery images and showing those
 images in collection view. My problem is that when I delete image from photo library
 then my app crashes as it is not able to fetch the PHAsset that has been deleted
 from the photo library. Here is my code to show the assets:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = photoCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageShowCell", for: indexPath) as! imageShowCell
     let image = photoArray.object(at: indexPath.item) as! Photos
     let imageManager = PHImageManager()
     let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [image.pic_name!], options: nil)[0]
    let scale  = UIScreen.main.scale
    let size = CGSize(width: 50.0 * scale, height: 50.0 * scale)
    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) { (image, _) in
        cell.imageView.image  = image
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a change observer with the photo library. You'll then get told when photos are deleted, inserted, changed or moved. The observer needs to inherit from `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver`. You then need to implement the function `photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange)`. If you use your view controller as the observer you should be able to catch all changes in the collection view as follows. The example below assumes you have an array of all the phAssets your collection view needs to displays its images readily available

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
        ...
    }

    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        // Change notifications may be made on a background queue.
        // Re-dispatch to the main queue to update the UI.
        // Check for changes to the displayed album itself
        // (its existence and metadata, not its member self).
        guard let photos = photos else {return}

        // Check for changes to the list of assets (insertions, deletions, moves, or updates).
        if let changes = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: photos) {
            // Keep the new fetch result for future use.
            photos = changes.fetchResultAfterChanges
            if changes.hasIncrementalChanges {
                // If there are incremental diffs, animate them in the collection view.
                self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    // For indexes to make sense, updates must be in this order:
                    // delete, insert, reload, move
                    if let removed = changes.removedIndexes, removed.count > 0 {
                        print("photoLibraryDidChange: Delete at \(removed.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section:0) })")
                        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: removed.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section:0) })
                    }
                    if let inserted = changes.insertedIndexes, inserted.count > 0 {
                        print("photoLibraryDidChange: Insert at \(inserted.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section:0) })")
                        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: inserted.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section:0) })
                    }
                    if var changed = changes.changedIndexes, changed.count > 0 {
                        print("photoLibraryDidChange: Reload at \(changed.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section:0) })")
                        // subtract removed indices
                        if let removed = changes.removedIndexes {
                            changed.subtract(removed)
                        }
                        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: changed.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section:0) })
                    }
                    changes.enumerateMoves { fromIndex, toIndex in
                        print("photoLibraryDidChange: Move at \(IndexPath(item: fromIndex, section:0)) to \(IndexPath(item: toIndex, section:0 ))")
                        self.collectionView.moveItem(at: IndexPath(item: fromIndex, section: 0), to: IndexPath(item: toIndex, section: 0))
                    }
                })

            } else {
                // Reload the collection view if incremental diffs are not available.
                ...
            }
        }

    }

    var photos : PHFetchResult<PHAsset>?
    weak var collectionView : UICollectionView!
}
```

Currently you are creating you PHAsset temporarily. You need a permanent PHObject of some form for the above function to be of any use. If you store individual PHAssets in your photoArray object you can use `PHChange.changeDetails(for object: PHObject)` on each of these to catch whether they have been deleted while the app was running. This won't work between sessions of the app though.

Instead of storing an array of local identifiers you could create an Album and store all the images your app uses in that Album. Then you can watch for changes to that Album.

As an aside the reason you are getting a crash is you are asking for array element [0] of an empty array. You can avoid the crash by checking the result of your `PHAsset.fetchAssets()` call has a count greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for quick  response @Spads. I tried using PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver but it needs PHFetchResult<PHAsset> to work with but I only have local Identifier of PHAssets in my core data by which I am fetching assets and then making images out of that. How do I use it with local Identifier of assets.

Comment: You can use `PHChange.changeDetails(for object: PHObject)` for individual PHAssets. I would create all your PHAssets and store them in your photoArray. You could go through all of them in `photoLibraryDidChange`

Comment: Added some more comments at the end of my answer

Comment: Does iOS notify of photos changes if the app is suspended or wakes up the app if terminated? If not is there a workaround to do this?

Comment: @ViruMax if the app is suspended it will receive the notifications at the point the user wakes it up, if I remember right.